# send push notification to android using Laravel

Tags: push-notification, laravel-5.8

I want to send notification to android and IOS devices using laravel 5.8. Please help me on recommending the best package for sending push notification.

when using this funcation This error appears "{"multicast_id":6507423456439771247,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}"

```
public function sendPushNotification($fcm_token, $title, $message, $id = null) {

    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $header = [
        'authorization:key=key',
        'content-type: application/json'
    ];

    $postdata = '{
        "to" : "' . $fcm_token . '",
            "notification" : {
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "text" : "' . $message . '"
            },
        "data" : {
            "id" : "'.$id.'",
            "title":"' . $title . '",
            "description" : "' . $message . '",
            "text" : "' . $message . '",
            "is_read": 0
          }
    }';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```